# Doctrine 2 Query Builder abs Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

This Work:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select("abs(u.code) as code")
       ->from("User", "u")
       ->orderBy("code","ASC")
       ->getQuery()
       ->getArrayResult();
```

This Don't Work:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select("u.code")
       ->from("User", "u")
       ->orderBy("abs(u.code)","ASC")
       ->getQuery()
       ->getArrayResult();
```

The Error:

**Syntax Error] line 0, col 118: Error: Expected end of string, got '('**

The native doctrine function abs work only on a select part of statment and
don't work on order by part.

Obs:

> 1-) Im avoiding to use NativeQuery.
>
> 2-) u.code is a varchar fild on mysql and need to be varchar ( some times numeric and some times string), and i need to order then like a number in numeric case.

Any Help?

Comment: but is a exceptoion throwed on ->getArrayResult(); inside a doctrine api

Comment: I think that you have an error in `ORDER BY` by expression. Try `$qb->select("u.code, abs(u.code) as abs_code") ->from("User", "u") ->orderBy("abs_code","ASC") ->getQuery() ->getArrayResult();`

Comment: this work i already try this, but my system sctructure is waiting the full object on select like this: $qb->select("u"), if i especify one field the struct ..puf!!

Comment: So use the `$qb->select("u.*, abs(u.code) as abs_code")`

Comment: The Doctrine parser sometimes is @#!dd look the error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near '*,s.*,t.*,w.*,abs(p.reference)': Error: Class Entity\Property has no field or association named *

Comment: my query have 4 inner joins and return a scalar result when i set a fild the result is changed to linear and .. puf!!

Comment: Modify your post with the real query.

Comment: it's complicated to post whole schema, but im folwowing your sugestion if work i go back here!! thank's a lot man!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved atma thank's `abs()` realy doesn't work directly in orderBy but as an alias.

soluction

```
SELECT field1,field2,abs(field3) AS abs_field3 
FROM table 
ORDER BY abs_field3 ASC
```

Obs: It's a doctrine limitation, not a mysql limitation, mysql suports abs direct on order by part.

Answer (score 0):

may be a little late after 7 years Inactivity, but maybe it helps somebody.

 Solution found here:
[Doctine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select("u.code")
   ->from("User", "u")
   ->orderBy(
       $qb->expr()->andX(
           $qb->expr()->abs('u.code'), "ASC"
       )
   )
   ->getQuery()
   ->getArrayResult()
;
```