# How to build a workaround with the fact that Doctrine 2 doesn't supportr ABS() SQL in ORDER BY field?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
public function getLakesNearby($minLat, $maxLat, $minLng, $maxLng, $lat, $lng, $limit)
{


    $query = $this->_em->createQuery('  SELECT a 
                                        FROM MycBundle:Lake a
                                        WHERE a.latitude > :minLat AND a.latitude < :maxLat AND a.longitude > :minLng AND a.longitude < :maxLng
                                        ORDER BY ABS(a.latitude - :lat) + ABS(a.longitude - :lng) ASC
                                        LIMIT :limit ');

    $query->setParameters(array('minLat' => $minLat, 'maxLat' => $maxLat, 'minLng' => $minLng, 'maxLng' => $maxLng, 'Lat' => $lat, 'Lng' => $lng, 'limit' => $limit));
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

This produce an error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 234: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

I saw that [Doctrine doesn't support ABS() in orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532886/doctrine-2-query-builder-abs-function).

Please help me to find a solution to make that work.

Thanks

Comment: The question you linked to *does* contain a solution.

Comment: not really, look at hat I am trying to do, I am trying to sort by the closest lat and lng from a certain point ($lat,$lng). Can't figure out how to express the same need with the nethod proposed in the linked post

Comment: Add that expression as a column with an alias and sort by that alias.

Comment: What about Square Root? Is it supported? Or something like IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for in QueryBuilder format.  This is off the top of my head and not in a place where I can test it so you might want to use this as a start.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('a');
$qb->from('MycBundle:Lake', 'a');

$qb->where('a.latitude > :minLat');
$qb->andWhere('a.latitude < :maxLat');
$qb->andWhere('a.longitude > :minLng');
$qb->andWhere('a.longitude < :maxLng');

$qb->add('orderBy', $qb->expr()->sum($qb->expr()->abs('a.latitude - :lat'), $qb->expr()->abs('a.longitude - :lng'));

$qb->setParameters(array(
     'minLat' => $minLat,
     'maxLat' => $maxLat,
     'minLng' => $minLng,
     'maxLng' => $maxLng,
     'lat'    => $lat,
     'lng'    => $lng)
);

$qb->setMaxResults($limit);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```