# How to order varchar as int in Symfony2 Doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('q')
    ->...
    ->orderBy('q.varcharCol')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

`varcharProp` is a varchar column containing values such as: 10, 10a, 101, 20, 300, 20b, 21, 200. I want to sort my entity by varcharProp but casting it as integer and I must do this ordering inside the query because I'm limiting the results.

It's possible to do something like this in Doctrine2?

```
entity->orderBy('ABS(q.varcharCol)')
```

Or changing `varcharProp` column type?

Comment: Nope, `Expected end of string, got '('`, same error using `ABS`

Comment: Ah.  If you add the expression to your select list, with an aliased column name, you can `orderBy()` the alias.

Comment: How can I do that using `createQueryBuilder`?

Comment: I mean, it's possible to select all the columns and the expression at once?

Comment: this is the same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532886/doctrine-2-query-builder-abs-function

Comment: Thanks, but not the same. I'm asking how to select all the columns at once AND the expression. Like, `$query->select('q.*, ABS('q.varcharCol')`. BTW, I realized it's impossible so I found a workaround.

Comment: I know you said it's impossible but I vaguely remember doing something like it. I used a `->addSelect('BLAH(blah blah) AS HIDDEN something')` which meant I could order by "something" while still just getting the objects in the return.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to approach this is adding a `select` with the `orderBy` expression as a hidden column. I mean:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
    ->createQueryBuilder('q')
    ->addSelect('ABS(q.varcharCol) AS HIDDEN foo')
    ->...
    ->orderBy('foo')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Thanks to @Qoop and @eggyal

Comment: Great! Thank you!