# Symfony and Doctrine: order by time difference

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to build a query that retrieves all the most recent and upcoming activities from database.

The entity `activity` has a field named `date` of type `DateTime`. So in my repository I was thinking of building something like this:

```
$query = $repository
          ->createQueryBuilder('a');
$query->orderBy( 'DATEDIFF( a.date, NOW())' , 'ASC');
$query->setMaxResults( 6 );
return $query;
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 59: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

The Dql that is generated by my query:

```
SELECT a FROM MyBundle\Entity\Activity a ORDER BY DATEDIFF( a.date, NOW()) ASC
```

I also tried installing `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`, but either it is not working or I was unable to configure it correctly.

Anyone has any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date_diff si already implemented as Doctrine DQL statement as described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)

for use as ordering statement I suggest you to use the HIDDEN select keyword as explained in [this](http://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) article

So your DQL is like this:

```
SELECT
    a,
    DATE_DIFF( a.date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ) AS HIDDEN score
FROM MyBundle:Entity a
ORDER BY score
```

And add the max result on the query. Let me know if you need help to adapt as query builder statement

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I added an abs to get both positive and negative values, and used the following query builder statement: `$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a'); $query->addselect('ABS( DATE_DIFF( a.date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ) ) AS HIDDEN score');$query->orderBy( 'score' , 'ASC');`

Comment: HI @Alberto you are welcome! Feel free to edit my answer with your final solution

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
$query = $repository
          ->createQueryBuilder('a');
$query->orderBy( 'DATEDIFF( a.date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())' , 'ASC');
$query->setMaxResults( 6 );
return $query;
```

?

Comment: Because I was hoping to get both recent (i.e. date < now) and upcoming (i.e. date > now) at once. Getting the absolute time difference with respect to current date would do it. On the other hand, your solution just order them chronologically.

Comment: Edited my answer above, it should work. But if I got your use case correct, you would probably need even an ABS function like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532886/doctrine-2-query-builder-abs-function